# nginx lowercase rewrite mod_pagespeed breaking images

Tags: mod-pagespeed

I have a rule that forces all URLs into lowercase and I think its breaking the image URL rewrites mod_pagespeed is making on my nginx server.

Is there a configuration I can change to prevent only allow lowercase renaming?

Answer (score 1):

Wow after 7 months of waiting.  I was having this problem as well.

**Here was my problem:**

```
location ~ [A-Z]  {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ http://example.com$uri_lowercase permanent;
   }
```

**Here is my fix:**

```
location /  {
       rewrite ^(.*)[A-Z]+(.*)$ http://example.com$uri_lowercase permanent;
   }
```

Comment: I noticed this still lowercases pdf files. Any idea why?